# How to delay a css animation which should start after a particular time

Tags: animation

I am using steps() in my css animation. Now I want to start the css animation after a particular time. Below is an example.

```
   @-webkit-keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width:455px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width:16.3em }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: black }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: black }
}
.typing_animation h3 {
position: absolute;
font-size: 36px;
width:455px;
left: 0;
top:110px;
font-style: italic;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: -48px;
letter-spacing: 4px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
     -webkit-animation: typing 10s steps(25, end), blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
     -moz-animation: typing 10s steps(25, end), blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
}
```

The above one results in a cool typing animation. However, it starts right away. I want to hold the typing and start it after a delay of say 5 seconds.

Thanks

**PS:** A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klmnweb/x0q7casz/) in case that's useful

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late but this is what you need:

1. Change your element width from "455px" to  "0" ;
2. Then add "animation-fill-mode: forwards" into your ".typing_animation h3" class, so this css rule force to animation can change the width;
3. Add your desired delay like this: "animation-delay: 3s".

Notice: Don't forget prefixes and if you use several animations on a element, it's better to use a shorthand animation property. [see tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

This is a example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pooria_h/75p4h82b/3/)

```
/* typing animation */
@keyframes typing {from {width: 0} to {width:19em}}
@-webkit-keyframes typing {from {width: 0} to {width:19em}}
@-moz-keyframes typing {from {width: 0} to {width:19em}}

/* blinking animation */
@keyframes blink-caret {from, to {border-color: transparent} 50% {border-color: #000000}}
@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {from, to {border-color: transparent} 50% {border-color: #000000}}
@-moz-keyframes blink-caret {from, to {border-color: transparent} 50% {border-color: #000000}}

.my-animation {
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
border-right: 0.1em solid #000000;
animation: typing 6s steps(30, end) 4s forwards, blink-caret 1s step-end 4s infinite;
-webkit-animation: typing 6s steps(30, end) 4s forwards, blink-caret 1s step-end 4s infinite;
-moz-animation: typing 6s steps(30, end) 4s forwards, blink-caret 1s step-end 4s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) property:

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 5s; 
animation-delay: 5s;
```

Note: Add this to the end of your h3 rule

Comment: Thanks. I did & it works. But until the animation (typing) starts, it should remain invisible. Sorry my question was a bit vague. Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/klmnweb/x0q7casz/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout function and add class to the particular element

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
$('p').addClass('text-show')  
}, 3000);
```

```css
p
{
  font-size:60px;
}

.text-show
{
 animation: textshow 2s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes textshow {
 0% {
  transform: scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>We Design.</p>
```

thanks,
Jomin George paul